# Ups and downs, climbs and falls

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

I climb 30 times
I fall 30 times
Not all times the same
vertical height I gain.
I learned that from my father
who climbs 6 times
and falls 6 times.
But if I stop
my father stops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it the

> Hands on a clock?

I think it is because:

> 30 times the minute hand will be ascending, and 30 times it will be descending.

Next,

> The father, the hour hand will go up 6 times and down 6 times

Then,

> Not all times are the same because when the hands move the time represented is different.

Lastly,

> If the minute hand stops, the clock is probably not working, so the hour hand will not move either.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Yes